# How to fix strange oracle PL/SQL error - "PLS-00049: bad bind variable"

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I am trying to write an execute an oracle PL/SQL function that return the number of records within a table, where one of the fields matches a certain name.

Here is my code:

```
create or replace function getNum
return number
as
v_x number;
begin
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :v_x
FROM UserResponses WHERE NHSPlatform_Name = 'Improvement Data and Analytics';
return v_x;

end;
/

execute getNum();
```

I keep getting strange errors:

> Function GETNUM compiled
>
> LINE/COL  ERROR
>   --------- ------------------------------------------------------------- 6/22      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'V_X' Errors: check compiler log
>
> Error starting at line : 85 in command - BEGIN getNum(); END; Error
>   report - ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00905: object
>   B7011343.GETNUM is invalid ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL:
>   Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Comment: Hi @J.Whitehead have you seen this answers and other answers ? Do you know how to accept an answer ?

Answer (score 2):

First thing is to correct your function as pmdba wrote in his answer.
This would then be a correct function:

```
create or replace function getNum
return number
as
v_x number;
begin
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_x
FROM UserResponses WHERE NHSPlatform_Name = 'Improvement Data and Analytics';
return v_x;

end;
/
```

Then you need to call your function in correct way. This is one way of calling it:

```
select getNum from dual;
```

[here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ca0e3e53c0af4f9765ae61e5c8f6d115)

Answer (score 1):

Drop the ":" from the select statement:

```
create or replace function getNum
return number
as
v_x number;
begin
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_x
FROM UserResponses WHERE NHSPlatform_Name = 'Improvement Data and Analytics';
return v_x;

end;
/

select getNum() from dual;
```

Comment: After doing this, the following error still occurs: Error starting at line : 85 in command -
BEGIN getNum(); END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00221: 'GETNUM' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: I updated the function call at the end to use a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SQL> VARIABLE ret_val NUMBER;
SQL> execute :ret_val := getnum;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select :ret_val from dual;
```